# Syntax error for Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax-error

I'm a beginner to Rails and Ruby, and I'm working on an elo system for a table that tracks players and their wins, losses, and elo.

Right now I'm getting the error

```
app/models/player.rb:36: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, 
expecting end-of-input):
app/controllers/players_controller.rb:3:in `index'
```

I've scoured all my files for a missing closing paren or bracket, but can't find anything. Here are some snippets of my code:

PlayerController index

```
def index
@players_items = Player.all.sort{|y,x| x.get_elo() <=> y.get_elo()}
end
```

PlayerModel methods

```
def get_elo()
    return self.elo
end

def update_weight()
    var = wins.count + lose.count
    if(var <= 6)
        self.weight = 50
    elsif(6 < var and var <= 15)
        self.weight = 25
    else
        self.weight = 15
    end
end

def update_elo(p2_elo, result)
    p1_elo = self.elo
    expected_score = 1 / (1 + 10 ** ((p2_elo - p1_elo)/400))
    self.elo += (self.weight * (result - expected_score)).round
end
```

If anyone could help me out, it would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: As requested, here is lines 27-36 of my Player model class

```
def win_percentage()
    var = wins.count + lose.count
        if(var == 0)
            return 0.001
    end
    else
        return ((wins.count * 6) - (lose.count * 4))
    end
end
end
```

Comment: This is invalid: `elsif(6 < var <= 15)`

Comment: I fixed that error, but the syntax error still occurs. The line highlighted under the extracted source is     @players_items = Player.all.sort{|y,x| x.get_elo() <=> y.get_elo()}

Comment: The error (which has a copy/paste issue because it has itself some syntax error, extra paren) is at `player.rb` line 36, but you only show part of that file so we can't tell which line is 36. The model is called from the controller, and the error is showing that as well. Can you show the lines around line 36 in `player.rb`?

Comment: @mbratch It is syntactically valid. But will cause a runtime error.

Comment: I've edited my main post with lines 27-36 of my player model class at the bottom

Comment: Don't write that information here. Write the line numbers in the question.

Comment: In your added code you have an `else` after your `end`. @Priti points out the error.

Comment: @mbratch see someone gave me down-vote. Did I miss anything? If I miss anything,would you help to point me out?

Comment: @Priti, my experience on S.O. is that anonymous dissenters occasionally appear somewhat randomly. I would ignore if you don't see the problem and they have trouble expressing their issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the issue:

```
if(var == 0)
            return 0.001
    end # <~~ why this end keyword ?
    else
        return ((wins.count * 6) - (lose.count * 4))
    end
```

It should be :

```
if(var == 0)
  return 0.001
else
  return ((wins.count * 6) - (lose.count * 4))
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `(6 < var <= 15)` is valid syntax, but does not make sense. It means `(6 < var) <= 15`.  Since `6 < var` would be `true` or `false`, it would then be evaluated as `true <= 15` or `false <= 15`, which will cause an error unless you have strangely overridden `<=>`.

You probably intended `(6 < var and var <= 15)`.

---

Update

You have two problems.

- You have `else`...`end` after `if`...`end`. You may have wanted `if`...`else`...`end`.
- You have an extra `end` at the end.

Your code does not look nice. It should be like:

```
def win_percentage
  return 0.001 if (wins.count + lose.count).zero?
  (wins.count * 6) - (lose.count * 4)
end
```

Comment: Oh I was unaware the logic syntax was written that way in Ruby. Unfortunately I tried that and it didn't resolve my issue. From the error message, the line highlighted with the error is 

    @players_items = Player.all.sort{|y,x| x.get_elo() <=> y.get_elo()}